# Matplotlib; making different subplots with different axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, subplot

I am making a figure that consists of 2 subplots. The subplots show different quantities so I would like the axis labels to be different. However, I have no idea how to do this with the matplotlib library.

Code example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequency = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)
eta = np.ones(10)

Power = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
T = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax[0].plot(frequency, eta)
plt.xlabel('frequency')
ax[1].plot(Power, T)


plt.show()
```

As you can see in the figure, the label appears underneath the second x-axis. [image]I have tried numerous things such as plt.axlabel('frequency', 'Power') or ax[0].xlabel('frequency') or fig[0].xlabel('frequency'), but none of them seem to work.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Just as you plot on a per-axis basis, add an `xlabel` to each axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequency = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)
eta = np.ones(10)

Power = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
T = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(frequency, eta)
plt.xlabel('frequency')

ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(Power, T)
plt.xlabel('label 2')

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5)

plt.show()
```

`plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)` means that the subplots in the figure are in the form of 2 rows and 1 column and the 1st subplot is currently being referred. Similarly, `plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)` means that the second subplot is being referred.

Without `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5)`, the label of the first subplot is hidden by the second subplot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I reckon this should work. 

I am going to have a loop around the plotting, because I want to plot 4 curves in 1 subplot. Is there a prettier way of making the axis labels outside this loop, or should I just keep it like this (meaning that the xlabel will be defined every time the loop is done)?

Comment: Do you want to display all the four curves in the same subplot, at the same time? In that case, i think you should refer to the appropriate subplot, use plt.plot() 4 times and then use one single plt.xlabel() statement.

Comment: Ah I think I figured it out at last. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: This worked perfectly.